# Gnome icons: how to get 24x24 size (not avail in distro)

Tags: icon

[Gnome](http://www.iconspedia.com/pack/gnome-desktop-2042/) icons have 48x48 / 64x64 sizes. I need sizes 24x24 or 22x22. I tried Irfanview: resize PNGs 48x to 24x. Result is bad: because of transparency I got bad pixels in output (edge is OK but corner of picture not). I played with IView settings. Cannot get OK result

Maybe available such size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnome desktop icons are available as SVG ([here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Desktop_icons) for example).

You can use [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org) and [export](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/File-Export.html) them at the desired resolution.